# background-size в некоторых браузерах

Tags: html, css, svg

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно поставить фоновую картинку для элемента меню, так, чтобы эта картинка была прижата к низу элемента, и растянута на всю его ширину. Делаю следующее:

```
    background-color:#fff;
background-image:url(../img/bg-active.svg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center bottom;
background-size:100% 27px;
```

В файрфоксе все работает, а в опере и хроме - картинка не растягивается, просто остаётся по нижнему краю элемента, и по его центру.

```
    -moz-background-size:100% 27px;
-ms-background-size:100% 27px;
-webkit-background-size:100% 27px;
-khtml-background-size:100% 27px;
-o-background-size:100% 27px;
```

Ничего из этого не помогает.

Буду благодарен за идеи.

Comment: `background-size: contain`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454685/cannot-stretch-svg-background-image-aspect-ratio-will-be-preserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

в ваш `bg-active.svg`

Совет [взят отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454685/cannot-stretch-svg-background-image-aspect-ratio-will-be-preserved)